# jaeger configuration in spring boot application when both of them are deployed on kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, jaeger

So, I am trying to trace logs of my spring boot application with jaeger so what are the steps that should be perform if my application and jaeger is deploy on kubernetes.
I have successfully deployed jaeger and spring boot application 
now how will I configure jaeger in my service.
My services are not visible in the jaegar console.

[image: showing all the services running on my kubernetes cluster]

I have added the following configuration to the yml:

```
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=localhost
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: jaeger
    labels:
      app: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: all-in-one
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: jaeger
          app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
          app.kubernetes.io/component: all-in-one
        annotations:
          prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
          prometheus.io/port: "16686"
      spec:
          containers:
          -   env:
              - name: COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT
                value: "9411"
              image: jaegertracing/all-in-one
              name: jaeger
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5775
                  protocol: UDP
                - containerPort: 6831
                  protocol: UDP
                - containerPort: 6832
                  protocol: UDP
                - containerPort: 5778
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 16686
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 9411
                  protocol: TCP
              readinessProbe:
                httpGet:
                  path: "/"
                  port: 14269
                initialDelaySeconds: 5
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: jaeger-query
    labels:
      app: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: query
  spec:
    ports:
      - name: query-http
        port: 80
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 16686
    selector:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: all-in-one
    type: LoadBalancer
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: jaeger-collector
    labels:
      app: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: collector
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: jaeger-collector-tchannel
      port: 14267
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 14267
    - name: jaeger-collector-http
      port: 14268
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 14268
    - name: jaeger-collector-zipkin
      port: 9411
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9411
    selector:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: all-in-one
    type: ClusterIP
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: jaeger-agent
    labels:
      app: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: agent
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: agent-zipkin-thrift
      port: 5775
      protocol: UDP
      targetPort: 5775
    - name: agent-compact
      port: 6831
      protocol: UDP
      targetPort: 6831
    - name: agent-binary
      port: 6832
      protocol: UDP
      targetPort: 6832
    - name: agent-configs
      port: 5778
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5778
    clusterIP: None
    selector:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: all-in-one
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: zipkin
    labels:
      app: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: zipkin
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: jaeger-collector-zipkin
      port: 9411
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9411
    clusterIP: None
    selector:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jaeger
      app.kubernetes.io/component: all-in-one
```

**Output og kubectl get service jaeger-query**

```
Name:                     jaeger-query
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=jaeger
                          app.kubernetes.io/component=query
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=jaeger
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"jaeger",
                            "app.kubernetes.io/component":"query","app.kuber...
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=all-in-one,app.kubernetes.io/name=jaeger
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.24.14.223
LoadBalancer Ingress:     35.222.40.241
Port:                     query-http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               16686/TCP
NodePort:                 query-http  30290/TCP
Endpoints:                10.20.2.7:16686
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: add output of kubectl get service jaeger --output yaml

Comment: What is the name of your app ?

Answer (score 2):

So the solution that works for me is -
I have made the following changes in my application.properties file of application

```
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=http://<load_balancer_ip_of_jaeger_service>:<expose_port>(example ":80")
opentracing.jaeger.http-sender.url=http://<cluster_ip_or_load_balancer_ip_of jaeger_collector>:<expose_port>/api/traces(example of expose port ":1468")
```

Comment: In my case , it is still not running . My Spring-boot-microservice and Jaeger both are running on kubernetes . I have added following parameter in application.properties i.e.                           opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=jaeger-agent
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831 ,

Answer (score 1):

You add `opentracing-spring-jaeger-starter` [library](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-jaeger) into the project which simply contains the code needed to provide a Jaeger implementation of the OpenTracing's `io.opentracing.Tracer` interface.

Since you have the jaeger deployed in Kubernetes and exposed it via a loadbalancer service you can use the loadbalancer IP and port to connect to it from outside the Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: yes I have already added this
I am asking about what is the  host value that i have to set in application.properties
for example if I have set it localhost when running application and jaeger on my system 
Then what will be the value when they are running inside kubernetes cluster

Comment: so you have a pod for jaeger and you have a service also? you can use  POD IP if you only have pod...if you have service then you can give the service name or you can give the service IP:PORT

Comment: kubectl describe svc servicename should give you IP and port of the service..you need to use that in the application.yaml..once that works you can directly use service name as well

Comment: opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=<load_balancer_ip>
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=80

So i have added this and after this my spring boot application was not able to start
right now I am running my application locally and my jaeger on kuberentes
and using jaere load balancer ip in my service as mentioned above

Comment: you need to whitelist your desktop IP in google cloud firewall to allow the traffic

Comment: is this IP 35.222.40.241 reachable from the local system where spring boot app is running? can you curl or ping or dig it?

Comment: yes I am able to open this ip on my browser and able to view jaeger ui on my firefox

Answer (score 0):

You should config:

```
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=jaeger-agent
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831
```

Comment: In my case , it is still not running . My Spring-boot-microservice and Jaeger both are running on kubernetes  (on local docker-desktop kubernetes)  . I have added following parameter in application.properties i.e. opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=jaeger-agent opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831

Comment: Do you add Jeager dependencies on Spring boot project?

Comment: @tuantam : Yes, I have added it . I have asked the same question on different post where I have given my github link ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63470148/jaeger-with-spring-boot-is-not-working-when-both-are-deployed-at-kubernetes