# Jaeger with spring boot is not working when both are deployed at kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, jaeger

I am trying to trace logs of my spring-boot-application with jaeger .

Both spring-boot microservice and jaeger are running on kubernetes ( local set-up on docker-desktop ) . My services traces are not visible in jaeger UI .

The same spring boot microservice and Jaeger local set up (without kuberntes ) is working fine .

Below is the configuration in my application.properties to interact with jaeger-agent in kubernetes .

```
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=jaeger-agent
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831
```

[image]

Below is my code :

https://github.com/anuragk3334/Spring-boot-and-Jaeger/tree/master/HelloWorld

Jaeger configuration is :

https://github.com/anuragk3334/Spring-boot-and-Jaeger/blob/master/HelloWorld/k8s/jaeger.yaml

```
$  kubectl describe svc jaeger-agent
Name:              jaeger-agent
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=jaeger
                   app.kubernetes.io/component=agent
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=jaeger
Annotations:       Selector:  app.kubernetes.io/component=all-in-one,app.kubernetes.io/name=jaeger
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                None
Port:              agent-zipkin-thrift  5775/UDP
TargetPort:        5775/UDP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.234:5775
Port:              agent-compact  6831/UDP
TargetPort:        6831/UDP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.234:6831
Port:              agent-binary  6832/UDP
TargetPort:        6832/UDP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.234:6832
Port:              agent-configs  5778/TCP
TargetPort:        5778/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.234:5778
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Can you check logs in spring boot app pod and jaeger-agent pod

Comment: My Spring-boot app is just a hello world application over HTTP get method.  trace-id,span-id and sample=true is getting generated in microservice  . But , I don't know what exactly I need to check in jaeger-agent pod .

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl describe svc jaeger-agent`. What do you put in the `application.properties` when you run it locally which works. Also check jaeger pods are running or not

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu : I have added the output  of kubectl describe svc jaeger-agent . In local system , there is no need of spring boot configuration , because it automatically  identifies the jaeger agent running on 6831 .

Comment: Is there any service shown Jaeger? Or is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried that and tested it with **OpenShift** environment. But in my case I use a [Jaeger Operator](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator) in my **OpenShift** environment.

You have to add an annotation which points to your Jaeger instance. You can refer to [this documentation](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/next-release/operator/). Check the deployment yaml fragment I've used in my deployment app below;

```
sidecar.jaegertracing.io/inject: jaeger-demo
```

Here you can find where it is defined, in the **metadata.annotations**;

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lev-restapp
  labels:
    tier: vertrouwd
    group: plooi-test
    ingress-frontoffice-policy: allow
    lev-label: lev-restapp
  annotations:
    sidecar.jaegertracing.io/inject: jaeger-demo # Inject Jaeger instance, must have unique name in cluster
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      lev-label: lev-restapp
  template:
    metadata:
...
```